# Arc length parameterization with non-zero base point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A parametrized $r(t),\, t\geq t_0$ is parametrized by arc length when $t=s(t)$, where the arc length $s(t)$ is given by
$$
\int_{t_0}^t\|r'(u)\|du.
$$

I was wondering if there is an example of an arc length parameterization with $t_0\neq 0$.

Comment: I think you mean $\int_{t_0}^t\Vert r^\prime(u)\Vert du$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, Thank you. I just edited the question.

Comment: With your definition, "no", because if $t = t_{0}$ the integral is $0$. But customarily, one says _parametrized by arc length_ if $\|r'(t)\| = 1$ for all $t$, i.e., if $s(t) = t - t_{0}$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see. Is "$\|r'(t)\|=1$" also equivalent to saying "An increment of the $\Delta t$ in the parameter corresponds to an increment of exactly $\Delta t$ in the arc length"? I think I could prove it.

Comment: Yes, that's right.